How to perform aggregate and add in power bi table
I have a table visualization in power bi created and I would want to show data in a column based on condition from another column. I have a country, users, and a bill in the dataset that is loaded. On the table visualization I want to only show the count of users having bill \>1.
What I have in the dataset:



country
users
bill




America
user1
1


America
user1
1


America
user1
1


America
user2
1


America
user2
1


UK
user4
1


UK
user4
1


UK
user5
1


UK
user6
1



What I want to look in the table visualization:



country
count of users who have greater than 1 bill




America
2


UK
1



I created below filter but it is not showing right numbers:
_filter = if(SUM('Table'\[Bill\])\>1, 1,0)


Looking for help. Can anyone please suggest.

pls try this
MEASURE =
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE ( Bill, Bill[country], Bill[users], "total", SUM ( Bill[bill] ) )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( _tbl, [total] > 1 ) )



Thanks for the reply. I tried this and created a new measure. But I'm not able to see the result. My intention is to use this result in the Table visual as a column. Can I use it that way to the already existing table visual?

what's the error message you got? I used the dataset that you provided to get the result

Hurray, It worked... able to add the measure to the visual table. There was no error as such but was not seeing the values calculated by the measure. Able to do it now. Thank you so much once again for helping. :)
